# How does WebAPK work? What's inside if you unpack the apk? Can this process be done manually with Android Studio CLI tools?

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, progressive-web-apps

I would like to learn about WebAPK, Here is steps I followed:

> 1. enable `improved-a2hs` from chrome://flags
> 2. go to `www.airhorner.com`
> 3. click `install` then `add`
> 4. This step took about 5~8 seconds.  I observed notification - download manager is downloading APK
> 5. app is installed

I tried to locate the apk, to see what's inside the APK. But I couldn't find it.

1. **Where can I find the downloaded APK?**
2. **What's inside of the APK?**

I am also trying to figure out how this whole process work.  My educated guess is:

> 1. URL sent to server when user click `install`
> 2. server grabs manifest from given URL
> 3. server create APK from above info
> 4. server returns download address back to the user
> 5. user device automatically download and install from the given link

**3. How does this whole process work?**

**4. Can I mimic the process with Android Studio CLI tools?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. List installed packages then `pull` from the phone.

   ```
   adb shell pm list packages | grep appName    
   adb pull patch/to/file ./
   ```
2. Minified version of the website

   ```
   AndroidManifest.xml  --> URL and manifest info as meta-data
   classes.dex          --> dalvic executable
   resources.arsc       --> resource files info
   /res                 --> resource files
   /META-INF            --> signing stuff
   /lib                 --> looks empty
   ```
3. I had some clues from the logcat.  Above guess seems legit
4. I'll try and update if it's possible

Comment: regarding 2) https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/android/webapk seems to be the source code template for the generated apk. Looks like a fairly complex setup where chrome and the webapk can even talk to each other via services. The content is displayed by chrome which is started from a transparent launcher activity in the webapk. Chrome is given the webapk's package name so it can extract the url and other config from the manifest `<meta-data />`.

Comment: @RNA, Any updates? I have a requirement to build WebAPK in local environment, I was wondering if it is even possible